# How we can create Vm with different number of MIPS in cloudsim?

Tags: java, cloud, virtual-machine, workflowservice, cloudsim

i create 10 vm by using loop.and every Vm use same number of MIPS , as the parameter for all the Vms are same .how i can create differnt vms with different mips?

```
    //VM Parameters
    long size = 10000; //image size (MB)
    int ram = 512; //vm memory (MB)
    int mips = 1000;
    long bw = 1000;
    int pesNumber = 1; //number of cpus
    String vmm = "Xen"; //VMM name

    //create VMs
    CondorVM[] vm = new CondorVM[vms];

    for (int i = 0; i < vms; i++) {
        double ratio = 1.0;
        vm[i] = new CondorVM(i, userId, mips * ratio, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared());
        list.add(vm[i]);
    }

    return list;
}
```

in the main method vmNum is initialized is equal to 10.

Comment: There are too many ways to do this. For instance, you could define VM profiles and read them from a config file. Please try to make your question a bit more specific so we can help you.

Comment: How to create 10 vm with differnt mips ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple is that. Create an  array of mips and pass it to vm constructor over a loop.

In your example:

```
long size = 10000; //image size (MB)
int ram = 512; //vm memory (MB)
int[] mips= {1000,200,3000,.....,500}; //Here's the array
long bw = 1000;
    int pesNumber = 1; //number of cpus
    String vmm = "Xen"; //VMM name

    //create VMs
    CondorVM[] vm = new CondorVM[vms];

    for (int i = 0; i < vms; i++) {
        double ratio = 1.0;
        vm[i] = new CondorVM(i, userId, mips[i] * ratio, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared());
        list.add(vm[i]);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Hope it would help you !!

Comment: Thank you so much Chand Korat :-)

Comment: I need yr help chanda in the implementation of fault tolerance technique in cloudsim..

Comment: This is the right place to discuss. You can add another questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Job migration algorithm is implemented in which class of workflowsim?or cliud sim?